# Kernel reboot without log during starting the crash kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, crash

I am testing crash kernel image feature with arm64 device, kernel version is linux-5.4, now i am trigger kernel crash via "echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger", then kernel would trigger null-pointer crash and save context, then start the second kernel.
Now i see kernel reboot without any log, so i need to find out the cause that kernel reboot.

console log is:

```
AP488B:/# echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
[04/17/2023 12:41:26.4299]  Kernel panic - not syncing: sysrq triggered crash
[04/17/2023 12:41:26.4299]  CPU: 1 PID: 8523 Comm: ash Kdump: loaded Tainted: P            E     5.4.164 #29
[04/17/2023 12:41:26.4999]  Hardware name: Qualcomm Technologies, Inc. IPQ8074/AP-HK02 (DT)
[04/17/2023 12:41:26.6099]  Call trace:
[04/17/2023 12:41:26.7099]   dump_backtrace+0x0/0x15c
[04/17/2023 12:41:26.7499]   show_stack+0x14/0x1c
[04/17/2023 12:41:26.8099]   dump_stack+0xb4/0xf8
[04/17/2023 12:41:26.8599]   panic+0x154/0x358
[04/17/2023 12:41:26.9199]   sysrq_handle_reboot+0x0/0x20
[04/17/2023 12:41:26.9599]   __handle_sysrq+0xa0/0x158
[04/17/2023 12:41:27.0299]   write_sysrq_trigger+0x98/0xa8
[04/17/2023 12:41:27.0799]   proc_reg_write+0x58/0x94
[04/17/2023 12:41:27.1499]   __vfs_write+0x18/0x38
[04/17/2023 12:41:27.1999]   vfs_write+0xd4/0x18c
[04/17/2023 12:41:27.2599]   ksys_write+0x70/0xd8
[04/17/2023 12:41:27.3099]   __arm64_sys_write+0x14/0x1c
[04/17/2023 12:41:27.3699]   el0_svc_common.constprop.0+0xfc/0x17c
[04/17/2023 12:41:27.4299]   el0_svc_handler+0x7c/0x84
[04/17/2023 12:41:27.4999]   el0_svc+0x8/0x680
[04/17/2023 12:41:27.5999]  SMP: cpu1 stopping secondary CPUs  0,2-3

jG▒Ԉ8▒%▒o▒#▒▒▒▒▒H▒▒
8B▒▒▒H▒▒
Board type: C9124AX

U-Boot DEV 2016.01 (btldr release 38) (Mar 31 2023 - 14:02:16 -0700)
```